# Relate fields and relationship in SuiteCRM

Tags: javascript, php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have the next problem : in my custom module "Schoold groups" i have [relate field to module "Places"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp99y.jpg) . Also i created one-to-many relationship between 'Places" and my custom field. And i need the next thing : when i go to certain PLACE page i'd like to see [all "School groups" that study at this place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwf2v.jpg). Is it possible to do it? It means that when i choose in relate field the place, the relationship should be autocreated.

Answer (score 0):

WHen you are created one-to-many relationship on "School group" and "Places" make sure primary module is "Places" and related module is "school group". and put "places" on the edit view layout. (so no need to create relate field on it). that's it. you are done now. open "places" you will get sub panel of "School group". all records which is linked with places will so there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The subpanel of related groups in "places" exists and related field in "groups" to "places" exists too, but when i choose some place nothing changes in subpanel, it's still empty..